# I want to add custom div after add to cart button on single product page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module

I am creating a custom extension for Magento 2. Currently i want to show custom div on single product page under Details tab.
How to achieve this ? can someone please give me tutorial or reference or guide me how to accomplish this in extension.
I am adding image for better clarification.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below file in your custom extension or theme

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml
```

create file in your module

```
vendorname/modulename/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml
```

Next create this file

```
vendorname/modulename/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

add below line of code on it.

```
<referenceBlock class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" as="description" template="vendorname_modulename::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
```

will be like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="mage/gallery/gallery.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
       <referenceBlock class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" as="description" template="vendorname_modulename::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
       </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: how i can use this in my custom module ?

Comment: create below path in your custom module  and copy pastse the core file then change it as per your req vendorname/modulename/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml

Comment: and layout.xml file will be under etc directory ?
or no need to create layout.xml file ?

Comment: no need just create above file the change it

Comment: i did this but nothing happened ? should i remove cache and setup upgrade ?

Comment: yes u have to remove cache and page  cache

Comment: i did cache thing but no luck :(

Comment: add below file vendorname/modulename/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml            then add the code below             
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="vendorname_modulename::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">

Comment: catalog_product_view.xml copy that file and add block at the end of file ?

Comment: no just addd below code only

Comment: updated Ans please check and try

Comment: <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">   i have tried with this and with your mentioned block. but nothing works

Comment: u have tried wrong

Comment: <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="vendorname_modulename::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">

please  mention your custom extension vendorname and module name vendorname_modulename

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126994/discussion-between-iqbal-malik-and-kanidhaya).

Comment: @iqbalmalik i have updated my ans please check and try it

Comment: <referenceContainer name="product.info.additional">
        <block name="loadbee_block" template="Shopventures_Loadbee::product/view/attributes.phtml" after="product.info.addtocart"/>
      </referenceContainer>  this block works for me but it is not entering the data under  the details tab. it put the data after tab

Comment: for detail tab i have updated the ans please check it chnageattribute.phtml

Comment: just try same code above it will work perfect, and accept the answer

Comment: no sir this code remove the details tab completely

Answer (score 0):

***USING CUSTOM THEME***

Go to `/app/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/`

Copy the file attributes.phtml into you custom theme under the following directory

```
Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view
```

Now change the file according to your needs, here is an example :)

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class);
    $_product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<?php if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData()) :?>
    <div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
        <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('More Information')) ?></caption>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data) :?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_data['label']) ?></th>
                    <td class="col data" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_data['label']) ?>"><?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
<?= 'HELLO WORLD' ?>
```

***USING CUSTOM MODULE***

Copy the file:

app\code\magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

into

app\code\vendor\module\view\frontend\layout\

replace the line:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
```

with

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
```

Copy

/app/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml

to

app\code\vendor\module\view\frontend\templates\product\view\

Comment: sir i am creating custom module / extension. not theme

Comment: updated, let me know if you need any further help

Comment: <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info"> that block is not  there in layout xml file

Comment: i think i am doing something wrong, can you please come on chat ?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: i cant add images in comments so i can show you what exactly the problem is

Comment: OK. Let's go to chat then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127021/discussion-between-iqbal-malik-and-joao71).